# "undefined method for integer" running a custom method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined

I'm trying to call a method I defined earlier in the code and it gives me this error:

```
"undefined method `filter' for 0:Integer (NoMethodError)"
```

This is the code:

```
def descending_order(n)

  @arrNum = n.to_s.chars.map {|i| i.to_i }
  @final = [@arrNum[0]]
  
  def self.filter(arr, ind)
    if self > arr[ind]
      @final.insert(ind, self)
    else
      self.filter(arr, ind+1)
    end
  end
  
  @arrNum.each { |i| i.filter(@final, 0) }
  
  return @final
    
end
```

I tried everything I could think of! Thanks

Comment: `i.filter(@final, 0)` ← that `i` is a number which doesn't have a `filter` method.

Comment: BTW, Ruby doesn't have nested methods. You should avoid defining one method within another. (unless you are doing metaprogramming)

Comment: Filter is an array method, an alias for select https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/filter

Comment: Haaa, ok! I should name different my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong!

If your intention is to return a reverse sorted array of a given number then the code snippet should be:

```
def descending_order(n)
  n.digits.sort.reverse
end
```

The above snippet returns following output

```
puts descending_order(352614)

=> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Or to present an alternative, we can skip the call to `#reverse` by simply sorting in reverse to start with.  `n.digits.sort { |a, b| b <=> a }`

Comment: Uf, thanks. I didn't know about the sort method